# Authentication Failed Sql Server JDBC Java 8

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a Sql Server database called "Shipworks1". This installation of SQL Server was installed by a shipping software called Shipworks. I cannot get the authentication to work for some reason. Here is my code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package daily.sales.report;

/**
 *
 * @author Line Computer
 */

import java.sql.*;

public class DailySalesReport {

   /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
   public static void main(String[] args) {

           Connection con = null;
           String conUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://LINECOMPUTER\\SHIPWORKS; databaseName=ShipWorks1; user=sa; password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;";

       try {
            // ...
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl);
        // ... 
      } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
             finally {
               if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
             }
    }

}
```

And my error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'. ClientConnectionId:916f2fe6-49c3-475f-bb09-f2ff14cd92c9
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:279)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:99)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4346)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3160)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3123)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1981)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at daily.sales.report.DailySalesReport.main(DailySalesReport.java:27)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I can connect to the DB in my db manger like so:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to pass conUrl without spaces ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decide, which type of authentication you want to use: Windows authentication or SQL authentication.

Perhaps it will work for you:

```
String userName ="username";
String password ="password";

String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://myDB\\SQLServer;databaseName=name";

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
```

Also, take a look on this - https://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/connecting-to-sql-server-from-java/